# Boolean function gives incorrect results

Tags: c#, class, foreach, boolean

I am trying to solve one of exercises on CodinGame. I thought I wrote a correct code, but the results are weird.

> A generation starship is heading towards a new home for mankind :
>   Sky's Edge. The exoplanet being several light years away, the journey
>   will last centuries and see multiple generations of crew members being
>   born, reproducing and dying in the service of human extrasolar
>   expansion. Your goal is to determine which life expectancies are the
>   best suited to reach Sky's Edge with at least 200 settlers, while
>   avoiding overcrowding the ship.
>
> The journey will last Y years, with a variable starting group of
>   people, on a starship having a maximum capacity of C. Every member of
>   the expedition will have exactly the same life expectancy.
>
> Every year, these modifications will take place in the given order : 1
>   - Every crew member will get older by one year. 2 - Every crew member exceeding the life expectancy will die. 3 - For each batch of 10 crew
>   members between the age of 20 and half the life expectancy (rounded
>   down), a baby is born, adding one 0-year-old individual to the crew.
>   These limits are inclusive.
>
> If the number of people exceeds the ship capacity C, overpopulation
>   causes a civil war leading to the destruction of the ship. The
>   expedition is considered successful if at least 200 people reach Sky's
>   Edge after Y years of travel.
>
> Your goal is to give the minimum and maximum life expectancies in
>   order to have a successful expedition. There is always at least one
>   valid life expectancy.

After some thinking I wrote this boolean function:

```
public static Boolean UpdateYear(int EXP)
{
    for (int i=0; i<Y; i++)
    {
        // AGING
        foreach (People person in Populace)
        {
            if (person.age != 10000)
                person.age++;
        }

        // DEATH
        foreach (People person in Populace)
        {
            if (person.age>=EXP)
            {
                person.age = 10000;
            }
        }

        // BIRTH
        int fertile = 0;

        foreach (People person in Populace)
        {
            if ((person.age>=20)&&(person.age<=EXP/2))
                fertile = fertile + person.number;
        }            

        int babies = fertile/10;
        People newBorn = new People(0, babies);
        Populace.Add(newBorn);

        new_people = 0;

        foreach (People person in Populace)
            if (person.age != 10000)
                new_people = new_people + person.number;


        total = new_people;

        if (total>=C)
            return false;


    } 
        if (total>=200)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

The correct answer for this case is: "true" for EXP (expectancy) 62 or 63, and false for all others.

When I try to run this function in Main just once, it gives correct result.

Example:

```
Console.Error.WriteLine(UpdateYear(61));
```

But when I try to run it a few times, no matter if by copying line, or by using a loop, it doesn't give correct result.

```
    for (int j=60; j<65; j++)
        Console.Error.WriteLine(UpdateYear(j));
```

The result I get is:

False
False
False
False
False

And supposed to be:
False (for 60)
False (for 61)
True(for 62)
True(for 63)
False (for 64)
False (for 60)

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There's *far* more code here than should be required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the question might be too rooted in "just learning c#" / OP doesn't appreciate the difference between static vs non-static enough to be able to reduce it to an MCV example..

Comment: @CaiusJard: In that case it should be closed as too broad. Stack Overflow basically isn't a good way to learn the basics of a language.

Comment: I agree, though I'm also keen to avoid disheartening new users by voting to close their questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made everything static, so there is only one instance of your list of people, but you make no attempts to reset it between successive runs (in your loop)

This means your first loop actions are still remembered when you go round your loop for the second time.

Perhaps don't make things static, or reset everything to the initial state each time you go round your loop

For what it's worth, i think i'd have modeled things differently, having a (non static) Ship as a container of (non static) Person, and I would have added and removed people to/from the ship when they born/died, etc each Person would have a n int indicating their age. Each year we count the viable fertile people, add new people according to the /10 rule, cull the too-old ones from the list..

Comment: I am still new to this. I guessed that first run results are saved, but didn't find a way to fix it, and I did try a lot before posting here. Can you make an example of either option?

Comment: Have you switched from saying "i don't want SO users to write the solution for me" to "i want the solution writing for me" ? Just trying to gauge how in depth you expect an example to be

Comment: I absolutely don't want solution. What I am asking - how I can call to function, if it isn't static, I get this error: "An object reference is required to access non-static member"

Comment: Oof.. That's kinda out of scope for even an SO answer, let alone a comment. You'd be better off following a tutorial that teaches the difference between static classes and instance classes. Or getting a book on C#, or even OO programming in general, seeing as the notions of static and nonstatic are pretty much the same regardless the language. SOmething like this might help: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members but if it seems "too intense" it indicates that you need to dig deeper into OO programming basics